# How I can emulate screen rotation with monkeyrunner with Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, rotation, genymotion

I use monkeyrunner script for testing APK with GenyMotion emulator at Windows. Is it possible that script rotate emulated device?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with Monkeyrunner, but if it's possible to run a CMD line via Monkeyrunner you can run the following command:

For horizonatal:

```
%Your_Genymotion_installation_path%\genyshell -c "rotation setangle 90"
```

For vertical:

```
%Your_Genymotion_installation_path%\genyshell -c "rotation setangle 0"
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Nir H.

I have created in the same folder with script - `rotate.bat` with this code:

```
"c:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion\genyshell.exe" -c "rotation setangle %1"
```

and call it from monkeyrunner as (example of rotate 90 degree and rotate it back):

```
...

print "rotation 90"
res = os.popen('rotate 90').read()
print res

MonkeyRunner.sleep(1)

print "rotation 0"
res = os.popen('rotate 0').read()
print res

...
```

and its works! :)