# Genymotion Emulator - rotate is not working all of a sudden

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I have been using the Genymotion Emulator for a few months now. The other day I went to rotate to landscape, and it won't let me.

Here's the things I've tried

- Click the Rotate Device Icon
- Downloading a fresh device configuration
- Click CMD-F11 .. I see the Rotate Device Icon flicker as if it was touched, but again .. still does not rotate
- Verified this is not at the app level, because I try it just from the Android desktop there .. no apps running

Can any one suggest a solution here

- what am I missing?
- do I need to reinstall Genymotion out right ?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516890/how-i-can-emulate-screen-rotation-with-monkeyrunner-with-android-emulator/28528242#28528242) can help you.